# Flutter Getx | Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'page' was called on null

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I had a perfectly working flutter project. I tried to implement GetX in it. I changed `MaterialApp()` to `GetMaterialApp()` and added few `GetXViews` and `Controllers`. Everything works fine and builds properly but, as soon as I added `getPages:[]` property to GetMaterialApp() it shows the following error.

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception:
> NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'page' was called on null.

I have also tried adding GetPages to the list like this 
`getPages: [GetPage(name:"/branch",page: ()=>BranchViewPage())],`

I was using flutter_bloc for the state management and had also implemented MultiBlocProviders in main.dart. The Routes were implemented with RouteGenerators.

Comment: can you share some more detail ?

Comment: @Shubhamhackz i have updated with the qn. is that fine??

Comment: The error is referencing a variable/class that has a getter called page.  That instance is null.  So, where ever you have your page getter, I'm guess that class was not instantiated before calling page.

Comment: but I havent given any page getter. As soon as I remove the getPages property from GetMaterialApp() the error vanishes. I think it is some issue associated with the Get package and some configuration on the package I have missed. @ScottGodfrey

Comment: Post your getPages.  Something in there is causing the issue.

Comment: Probably wouldn't have used `get.find()`

Comment: Did you add Binding to the page?